# jQuery Selector Help Next Class

Tags: jquery-selectors

Im stuck on something and although there is 1000 different ways to select what I need, I cant get it going.

In the HTML below, the `<tr class="hide">` is hidden, and when someone clicks the link in the span, I want it to slidedown.

I've tried

```
$(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow');
```

and a bunch of other similar things, but no love. It seems because the hidden tr element is down 2 levels I cant select it.

Mind you, there will be multiple of these on a page, it needs to be the next one in line that slides down, so I cant just $('.hide') select it.

Can someone help?

Heres my HTML

```
<td>
    <span class="details">Details</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide">
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: If this answer helps you, mark it as correct for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code you wrote is being triggered when a user clicks the span, then your code is not going high enough up the DOM to get to the next TR. What you need is this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().slideToggle('slow');
```

The first `parent()` gets you to the `<td>`, and the second one gets you to the `<tr>`.

Comment: This looks like it would work too.  Thanks for your response. Gotta love stackoverflow :)